# How does poison work in Worms Reloaded?

Tags: pc, worms-reloaded

If a worm get poisoned in Worms Reloaded, is possible to remove it in some way?

And another question, how often and how much life is removed when a worm is poisoned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cure a poisoned worm, just collect a health crate with it.

Poisoned worms lose 5 health points per turn.

Answer (score 1):

Note that worm can't die with poison only - its health always stops decreasing at 1.